# Tetrachoric correlations using hetcor different when variables are stored as factor vs numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a factor analysis with a series of binary variables. I'm using the `hetcor` function to obtain tetrachoric correlations. The tetrachoric correlations are much smaller when the variables are stored as numeric as opposed to factor. Does anyone know why this would be, or if I should be concerned? I ran a tetrachoric correlation matrix in Stata, and the matrix matches the one produced in R with factors.

The data below do not produce the same size of differences in the correlations that I'm seeing in my data, and I haven't been able to figure out how to share my data on stackoverflow (in spite of a lot of searching), but this is the code I'm using to produce the correlations and what the data look like (15 binary variables, n=6157).

```
set.seed(5)

df <- tibble(x1 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x2 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x3 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x4 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x5 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x6 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x7 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x8 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x9 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x10 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x11 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x12 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x13 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x14 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157),
            x15 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 6157))

# Tetrachoric correlations with numeric variables 
tetrachoric_num <- hetcor(df)$cor
cor.plot(tetrachoric_num, numbers=T, upper=FALSE, main = "Tetrachoric Correlations with numeric variables", show.legend = TRUE)

# convert all columns to factors
df[sapply(df, is.numeric)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], as.factor) 

# Tetrachoric correlations with factor variables 
tetrachoric_factor <- hetcor(df)$cor
cor.plot(tetrachoric_factor, numbers=T, upper=FALSE, main = "Tetrachoric Correlations with factor variables", show.legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you show an example? This would help others understand and answer this question.